# Checkbox Values stored in DB and want to display

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli

Please see this link 
http://thedesigningworld.com/bea

Here's a Small form contains 8-9 fields + a group of checkboxes
I want to save all details in DB + want to display in a table in proper manner, but it not works properly

Here's the code which i used

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST[wert1]);$i++)
{
if($_POST[wert1][$i]!= "")
 { 
 $check1[] =$_POST['wert1'][$i];  } }
 $new1=implode(',', $check1);



$result = "INSERT into table1(check1) values($new1)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $result);
```

So i've one doubt that for each checkbox row, should i need to define same array name or different like here i used array name as wert1[] for first row

Comment: Here's the admin Section where i want to display whole details - http://thedesigningworld.com/bea/admin/admin.php

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox values are not transmitted if the box is not checked.

If you have influence, you could put a hidden input field of the same name before the checkbox and the value "0", like:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox_name" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="1">Some Text</input>
```

In you example site, you're using array notation, which is basically a good thing. However, you have not given an index so you might not recognize missing elements.

Comment: Could you please have a look at online, what i did and what needs to be done,, ?? even i need a code for display array elements from Database

Comment: With the current form, you can use the following code :

    foreach($_POST['wert1'] as $value) {
      $values = explode('_', $value);
      // $values[0] contains "Aargau", $values[1] contains "Kurse"
    }


edit: code is not good readable

Comment: Please add me on skype so that i can explain to you in better way ...My skype - iamchetansoni

Comment: Thanks for all, finally i fixed it  . so much love :)